# How to get ExecuteSQL output format from octa-stream to Avro format

Tags: apache-nifi

We have noticed NIFI test and prod having issue when viewing the content of queued items. After ExecuteSQL, we get an avro format file by default, and was supposed to be able to view the content of the file. But now, the content-type is shown as application/octet-stream and impossible to view the content as formatted any more.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84kil.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRJ9V.png)

Not finding option to change the output format to Avro in Nifi 1.20.0.

Answer (score 1):

After ExecuteSQL, the `mime.type` attribute should be set on the FlowFile to `application/avro-binary`, which is recognized by the content viewer. Also the filename should be a UUID but in your screenshot ends in `.txt`. That might cause the content viewer to think it's a plain file and not Avro. Was there a processor in between ExecuteSQL and the connection/queue you put in your screenshot that changed the attributes and/or content?

As an alternative, you can use ExecuteSQLRecord and configure an AvroRecordSetWriter for it.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I have tried with the following options but still getting same problem.
1. Add attribute in the flow file
mime.type = application/avro-binary
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSo44.png)
2. Also I tried with ExecuteSQLRecord.20.0 as suggested by you bit still I am getting output in the application/octet-stream format

Comment: How is your AvroRecordSetWriter configured?